# Codeigniter 3 / Ajax / Not receving post datas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to achieve post some datas on Ajax for save inside a controller, but definitly impossible to get them inside my controller, each time the post is empty.

This is my ajax code ( simple version, but not work at all too ):

```
$(document).on("click",'.ajax_test',function(){

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:_SITE_URL+"ajax-test",
        ContentType : 'application/json',
        cache:false,
        data:{'test':"ok"},
        success:function(msg){
                alert(msg);
        },
        fail:function(msg){
            alert("failed");
        }
    });

});
```

And my Controller :

```
public function test_ajax(){

if($this->input->is_ajax_request()):
    echo $this->input->post("test");
endif;  }
```

When i send it, no problem with the link, but my javascript return strictly nothing. I tried a lot of things, my config looks ok ( csrf_protection is at false now )
It worked perfect with CI 2, but since i migrate to CI 3 this refuse to work. So what am i doing wrong ? Or what kind of configuration i need to check on codeigniter ?

Thanks a lot by advance

Comment: Do a print_r($_POST) and see what that shows. Also verify $this->input->is_ajax_request() is true.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ContentType : 'application/json',` from your ajax options. It is not needed and is confusing things. When you set the ajax option `data:` to an object (like you correctly are) it will be sent to the server in the way the controller is expecting.

The other possible problem is with the .ajax url option. You have

```
url:_SITE_URL+"ajax-test",
```

And if `_SITE_URL` isn't right then the controller won't be found. resulting in

> 404 Page Not Found

You are not seeing the error because you have used the wrong ajax option with

```
`fail:function(msg){`
```

`fail` is actually a function. Subtle difference between option and function here. Examine the proper use below. 
Putting it all together your ajax call should look like this

```
 $.ajax(
 {
      type: "POST",
      url: "controller_name/ajax-test",
      cache: false,
      data: {test: "ok"},
      success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
      },
  }).fail(function () {
    alert("failed");
});
```

Note how `.fail` is chained to `$.ajax()` and not used in the set of ajax options.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  Well, my global _SITE_URL was defined ( reffer to base_url ), but, it's a multi-lang, and i simply missed to pass the lang for the request link.. So, i no had any bug for obtain the controller, but he never taked with "him" the datas. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

I use this template of AJAX Request:

```
    var _data = {};     
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/mycontroller/myfunction",
                data: {
                    insertiondata: _data
                },
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                complete: function() {

                },
                success: function(_result) {
                    console.log(_result)
                }
            });
```

In the controller i catch the params like this :

```
...
class Mycontroller extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {}
    public function myfunction(){

        $mydata= $_POST['insertiondata'];
        ....
}
...
```

Hope this help.
Good Luck,

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the function `test_ajax` on your url use dataType

```
$(document).on("click",'.ajax_test',function(){

    var SITE_URL = "<?php echo base_url();?>";

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: SITE_URL + "ajax_test/test_ajax",
        cache:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{
            'test':"ok"
        },
        success:function(msg){
            alert(msg['test']);
        },
        error:function(msg){
            alert("failed");
        }
    });
});
```

> Make sure your file names and class names only have the first letter upper case. Codeigniter case sensitive.

Filename: Ajax_test.php

Use json_encode

```
<?php

class Ajax_test extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
}

public function test_ajax(){

    $data['test'] = $this->input->post("test");

    echo json_encode($data);

}

}
```

Comment: `url: SITE_URL + "ajax_test/test_ajax",` should be `url: "<?php echo site_url('ajax_test/test_ajax');?>",`